# ng build --prod not running

Tags: javascript, angular, git, web-deployment

When I type `ng build --prod` on my angular 7 projects to deploy on GitHub pages it is giving an error.

> ERROR in scripts.2151a8359c37a8233d82.js from Terser
>   Unexpected token: punc (:) [scripts.2151a8359c37a8233d82.js:6,3]

What can I do to solve this error?

Comment: Similar to [this](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/issues/1086)